# Sub Query having group by and count

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

**tbl_Offer**

```
OFID bigint
Offer_Text text

OFID    Offer_Text   
-------    ----------    
1014    Test1   
1015    Test2
```

**tbl_TransactionDishout**

```
offerNo   TerminalID      Created
---------------------------------
1014      170924690436418 2010-05-25 12:51:59.547
```

**tblVTSettings**

```
gid      mid       tid
-----------------------
50       153       119600317313328
104      158       160064024922223
76       162       256674529511898
1111     148       123909123909123
```

These are the three tables.

Now I want the information of all deals (offers) separated by schools (look gid where TerminalID in (50,76,104)).

These are the three schools: (50,76,104)

The o/p should have these fields:
OfferID(OFID), School the offer is for, Offer_Text, Number of time the offer is.

The query may be somehow like this:

```
    SELECT OFID, Offer_Text,
    Counter = 
    (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.tbl_TransactionDishout t 
    WHERE t.OfferNo = CAST(OFID AS NVARCHAR(30)) 
    and t.TerminalID in 
    (select TID from tblVTSettings where gid in (50,76,104))
    )
    FROM dbo.tbl_Offer 
    Where EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.tbl_TransactionDishout 
          WHERE OfferNo = CAST(OFID AS NVARCHAR(30)))
```

Comment: I am getting OFID, Offer_Text and Counter with above query but not getting from which school it belongs to..

Comment: @marc_s can you give me the correct output..?

Comment: I don't get it. There is no connection between offers and schools.

Comment: This is the relation:
TerminalID in 
    (select TID from tblVTSettings where gid in (50,76,104))
    )

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
SELECT to.OFID
      ,ts.gid AS 'School the offer is for'
      ,to.Offer_Text
      ,COUNT(to.OFID) AS 'Number of time the offer is'
  FROM tbl_Offer to
  JOIN tbl_TransactionDishout tt
    ON to.OFID = tt.offerNo
  JOIN tblVTSettings ts
    ON ts.tid = tt.TerminalID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT o.OFID,
       s.gid,
       o.Offer_Text,
       count(*) over (partition by o.OFID) number_schools,
       count(*) over (partition by s.gid) number_offers
  FROM tbl_Offer o
  JOIN tbl_TransactionDishout d ON o.OFID = d.offerNo
  JOIN tblVTSettings s ON s.tid = d.TerminalID
```

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'over'.

Comment: @VishalSuthar: Due to a missing comma after `o.Offer_Text`, which I have now corrected - try again.

Comment: @VishalSuthar: I have just tried it in SQLServer with the table structure as provided - it runs without error. Have you changed any of the table or column names?